# How to access editable div inside of angular component

Tags: angular, contenteditable

I`m looking for way to access div from html template
I have this in html

```
<div #postStatus contenteditable="true" class="form-control" placeholder="" (keyup)="postForm.value.content=postStatus.innerText"></div>
```

And now I need to access that value to reset it in function which takes this value to const which I sending with request. I have tried this

```
postStatus.innerText = null;
```

But this gives me error:

```
ERROR ReferenceError: postStatus is not defined
```

Is there any proper way to access that value from my component.ts file?
And also to have different text which person see and which actualy is submiting (it must be @[mongoose object id], but user need to see name and surname of person which they picked from list that apears when they start writing @+upper case, but if they not pick, but write name and surname even with @ it must be shown exact text of what they written)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work :

```
 import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

   class SomeCmp {
      @ViewChild("postStatus") postStatus : ElementRef;

      reset(){
        this.postStatus.nativeElement.innerText = "";

      }
    }
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-se3uqf)**

Comment: Wouldn't you have to do `this.postStatus.nativeElement.innerText`?

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Now only question remains how it`s possible to have in innerText @[mongoose obj.id], but for user in field show just some other related data, but if user delete that data, then also remove this @[mongoose obj.id]

Comment: you can not do that . if you changed the innerText, the filed will show the innerText value

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine Then how FB does users taging?